# Pause rootEpic until persist completion

Tags: redux, rxjs, react-redux, rxjs5, redux-observable

I'm using redux-persist and redux-observable in my application and noticed that my API calls wrapped in observable are happening before store state is restored. And restoration overrides fetched value with stale data.
How could rootEpic be paused, while buffering, until persist/REHYDRATE action arrives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanna wait until an "event" occurred you can use `.skipUntil`. For example:

```js
const action$ = new Rx.Subject();

// In your epic
action$
  .skipUntil(action$.filter(({ type }) => type === 'hydrated'))
  .subscribe(x => console.log(x));

// "Rehydrate"
action$.next({ type: 'hello!' });
action$.next({ type: 'hello?' });
action$.next({ type: 'any body there?' });
action$.next({ type: 'hydrated' });
action$.next({ type: 'do' });
action$.next({ type: 'you' });
action$.next({ type: 'see' });
action$.next({ type: 'me' });
action$.next({ type: 'now' });
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

I guess, in order to not add this to all of your epics, you could `.mergeMap()` your root epic or something :)

---

*After discussion in the comments below*:

This issue might also occur with other middleware. Thus, it might be a better solution to not fire any actions until the re-hydration is done.

Comment: In your code all actions came before 'hydrated' are discarded. Instead, they should be buffered and replied back into the epics after 'hydrated'.

Comment: Sorry, thought this is what you wanted :-x But shouldn't your app rather not fire any actions until state is rehydrated? It seems like you would run into the same issue with other middleware.

Comment: >>But shouldn't your app rather not fire any actions until state is rehydrated?
That would work just as well.

I have following archirecture, component fires action (e.i. FETCH_BACKGROUND). Epic intercepts this action and sends a request to the server getting a background url. After middleware gets a response from server it fires FETCH_BACKGROUND_SUCCESS which sets the background url in state.
In my case, however, REHYDRATE which runs after goes and rewrites newly set state.

Comment: After some thought, I think you are right, and it's better to handle caching on a component level. So I intend to do. Please edit your solution, so I could mark it as a correct answer. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with redux-persist, but it may or may not be important to note that the order in which you pass in middleware to redux matters. Some middleware needs to be before or after others. If this sounds relevant to your issue, you might try swapping them.

Comment: Actually, it's not related to the order, i also have the same issue and i tried both of them